# emacsclient --eval command to bring a background emacs window to front

Tags: emacsclient, find-file, eval, eval-expression

Suppose I already opened a emacs but its in the background. So, is there an emacsclient eval option that I can type in the shell like:

```
emacsclient --eval "(bring-existing-emacs-window-to-front)"
```

To bring the background emacs window to the front?

This can be pretty handy, since I'm always using 
`emacsclient -c --eval "(find-file \"afile\")"`. Which unfortunately opens the frame in the background instead of front.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `select-frame-set-input-focus` to give focus to a given frame:

```
emacsclient --eval '(progn
                      (find-file "file.txt")
                      (select-frame-set-input-focus (selected-frame)))'
```

But, if you only want to open a file, don't use `--eval`:

```
emacsclient -c file.txt
```